# What is the limiting distribution of $R$?

Tags: probability, statistics

For three independent random variable sequences $X_n,Y_n,Z_n$, we have $X_n\xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$ (which means $X_n$ converges to Standard Gaussian distribution in distribution), $Y_n\xrightarrow{d} N(0,1), Z_n\xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$. Therefore, the square each of them (say, $X_n^2$) converges to $\chi_1^2$ in distribution.

Comment: No... Notice that $X+Y-Z$ has some probability to be negative number, but $\chi_1^2$ is always positive.

Comment: The reason is the same... $R=X^2+Y^2-Z^2$ still can be negative. What is $O_p(n^{-1/2})$?

Comment: I know that notation... but I don't think it should be here...

Comment: Now it makes sense, but the answer is the difference distribution between $\chi_2^2$ and $\chi_1^2$, and I think this maybe in the MSE somewhere... Definately not $\chi_1^2$.

Comment: I am going to edit it, would you like to check?

Comment: @JetfiRex Don't we need independence of $X_n,Y_n,Z_n$ *and* independence of their limits in distribution for the limit of the sum of their squares to be the sum of their limits?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I am not sure, but I think the standard Gaussian are independent standard Gaussian (you could add your edit to the original question, too). I am not sure whether we can derive from the independence of $X_n,Y_n,Z_n$ to the independence of three limiting Gaussian distributions, but I suspect it can (at least I am unable to come up with a counterexample.) Also, I don't take charge of the correctness of the original question, since I only clarify some things that I need to add based on the comments.

Comment: ok, let me know if my response makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need some additional assumptions. Remember convergence in distribution is simply a statement about pointwise convergence of CDFs, so it doesn't tell us about the underlying probability spaces.

First, if $U_n,V_n$ are independent and if $U,V$ are independent and if $U_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}U,V_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}V$ then $U_n+V_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}U+V$.  You can show this using characteristic functions (remember convergence in distribution is equivalent to pointwise convergence in characteristic functions via Levy's continuity theorem).

To appeal to this result, I will assume $X_n,Y_n,Z_n$ are independent and they respectively converge in distribution to $X,Y,Z$ that are *also independent* and identically standard normal; then I think we can obtain the limiting distribution of $R_n$.

The $O_p(n^{-1/2})$ term converges in distribution to constant zero, so by the continuous mapping theorem and the above independence result, we have

$$R_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X^2+Y^2-Z^2=W^2-Z^2$$

where $W^2\sim \chi_2^2,Z^2\sim \chi^2_1 $ are independent. Independence tells us the characteristic function of $W^2-Z^2$ is given by

$$\varphi(t)=(1-2it)^{-1}(1+2it)^{-1/2}.$$

Comment: I am not really sure that if $U_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}U,V_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}V$ and $U_n,V_n$ are independent, then why can't we derive $U,V$ are independent... Since we can know that for any interval $I_1$ and $I_2$, $\mathbb P(U_n\in I_1)$ and $\mathbb P(V_n\in I_2)$ converges to $\mathbb P(U\in I_1)$ and $\mathbb P(V\in I_2)$.  Since they are independent, we know that $\mathbb P(U_n\in I_1, V_n\in I_2)=\mathbb P(U_n\in I_1)\mathbb{P}(V_n\in I_2)$ converges to $\mathbb{P}(U\in I_1)\mathbb P(V\in I_2)$,

Comment: So this will imply that for any rectangle $I_1\times I_2$, we have the probability of $(U,V)$ in that rectangle eqals to the product of  $\mathbb P(U\in I_1)$ and $\mathbb P(V\in I_2)$. We could generalize the argument from intervals/rectangles to the events of Borel sigma algebra, which further means that $U$ and $V$ are independent...

Comment: @JetfiRex I don't see how  that proves independence of $U,V$.  You just essentially showed that the joint CDF of $U_n,V_n$ converges to the product of the limiting marginal CDFs. Remember $U_n$ weakly converging to $U$ and $V_n$ weakly converging to $V$ doesn't imply $(U_n,V_n)$ weakly converges to $(U,V).$ As for a counterexample, let $V$=$-U$ where $U$ and $V$ are standard normal and $U_n,V_n$ are independent. We know nothing about the probability space in which their limits live.

Comment: Oh I see what's going on here... Notice that I see $U,V$ **jointly** as **their** limiting distribution of $U_n$, $V_n$, so I assumed that the distribution $U,V$ are in the "same kind of probability space" of $U_n,V_n$ (and so, the joint distribution of $U,V$ is the limiting distribution of $U_n,V_n$)... it is like, in coding, the "standard normal" is actually a reference or a value there. If we "pass by value", you are right, we don't know anything. I regarded $U$ as "the marginal dist. of limiting dist. of joint $U_n,V_n$" so there's no doubt that in this scenario, $U$, $V$ are independent.