# Can we have $ \frac{1}{2} X_n^2+\frac{1}{2} Y_n^2\to \frac{1}{2}\chi_1^2+\frac{1}{2}\chi_1^2 $?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be two iid sequences of random variables with $N(0,1)$. Then $X_n^2\to \chi_1^2$ in distribution and $Y_n^2\to \chi_1^2$, can we have
$$
\frac{1}{2} X_n^2+\frac{1}{2} Y_n^2\to \frac{1}{2}\chi_1^2+\frac{1}{2}\chi_1^2
$$
in distribution? Or it should be $\frac{1}{2} \chi_2^2$?

Comment: We had a similar discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373561/what-is-the-limiting-distribution-of-r) no? The limiting random variables should be independent to say their sum is $(1/2) \chi^2_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that if for all $n$ both $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distributed, then their squares are also both $\chi_1^2$ distributed. Therefore an equal (in distribution) sign would be more appropriate than a limit sign.

Maybe what you had in mind instead was that $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ were two independent sequences both converging in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,1)$ ? In that case it indeed follows from the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) that $X_n^2 \to^d\chi_1^2$ and $Y_n^2 \to^d\tilde\chi_1^2$ ($\chi_1^2 $ and $\tilde\chi_1^2 $ are independent).

Regardless, regarding your question, you can show (e.g. using characteristic functions) that for any two **independent** sequences of r.v. $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ with $A_n\to^dA$ and $B_n\to^dB$, it holds that $A_n + B_n \to^d A +B$. Therefore it is true that
$$ \frac{1}{2} X_n^2+\frac{1}{2} Y_n^2\to^d \frac{1}{2}\chi_1^2+\frac{1}{2}\tilde\chi_1^2 = \frac 1 2\left(\chi_1^2 + \tilde\chi_1^2\right) $$
But note that the sum of two independent $\chi^2$ variables with one degree of freedom [is also a $\chi^2$ with two degrees of freedom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096298/question-about-sum-of-chi-squared-distribution), therefore
$$ \frac 1 2\left(\chi_1^2 + \tilde\chi_1^2\right) =^d \frac 1 2\chi_2^2$$
So the two formulations are equivalent.

---

**Bonus :** You can also notice that $X_n^2 + Y_n^2\to^d Z^2 + \tilde Z^2$ where $Z$ and $\tilde Z$ are independent $\mathcal N(0,1)$ so
$$ \frac{1}{2} X_n^2+\frac{1}{2} Y_n^2\to^d \frac 1 2 \left(Z^2 + \tilde Z^2\right) =^d \frac 1 2 \chi_2^2 $$
Which is once again the same thing.

Comment: "For any two **independent** sequences of r.v. $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ with $A_n\to^dA$ and $B_n\to^dB$, it holds that $A_n + B_n \to^d A +B$" Don't you need $A$ and $B$ to be independent too? I discussed this issue in the comments for a related question OP asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373561/what-is-the-limiting-distribution-of-r)

Comment: Good remark. I read your discussion in the other post but I still don't think there is a need to assume independence of $A$ and $B$, because since the convergence is in distribution only, we can always say, e.g. $A_n\to^d \tilde A$ with $\tilde A$ a copy of $A$ independent of $B$.